# How to add line to CartoDB map?

Tags: carto

According to the CartoDB tutorial on [how to add and edit geometries](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/adding_geometries.html), using the CartoDB editor, when we click *Add Feature*, we should get a popup box with three options:

- Add point
- Add line
- Add polygon

But when I click that, I only get the **Add point** option.
Have the other two options moved somewhere else?
Or is there another way to add a line?

Answer (score 1):

In one layer you can only have one kind of geometry (polygon, line or point). It seems that you already have some points in the table and now only this option appears. You can change it by deleting all points and refreshing the page, but if you want to include different geometries in your map, you should create a new table with the lines and add it to your previous table as a new layer.

By using three layers you'll be able to have the three available geometries in a map.